# How to read from file in C++ into a queue to make postfix evaluation?

Tags: c++, file, stack, queue, structure

I am new to C++. I am trying to do an exercise where I supposed to read postfix operations into a queue and then evaluate it using stack. In my file every line includes only one postfix operation and all operations thus lines ends with #. But I couldn't make the reading part. My function for that only does it job for 2 times but it needs to do 3 times.

Here is what I managed to write so far:

> //queue cpp file

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include "Queue.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

using namespace std;

Queue::Queue(){

    Size = 0;
    head = NULL;
    rear = NULL;
}

Queue::~Queue(){
    Node* curPtr = head;
    while( curPtr != 0 ) {
        Node* nex = curPtr->next;
        delete curPtr;
        curPtr = nex;
    }
    head = 0;
}

bool Queue::empty() const {

    if(Size==0){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

int Queue::size() const {

    return Size;
}

void Queue::enqueue(ElementType x){

    Node *newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = x;

    if(Size == 0){
        rear=head = newNode;
        Size++;
    }
    else{
        rear->next=newNode;
        rear=rear->next;
        Size++;
    }
}

void Queue::dequeue(){

    Node * newNode;

    if(Size==1){

        newNode=head;
        rear=NULL;
        head=NULL;
        delete newNode;
    }
    else{
        newNode=head;
        head=head->next;
        delete newNode;
    }
    Size--;
}

ElementType Queue::front(){

    return head->data;
}


//queue .h file

#ifndef QUEUE
#define QUEUE

using namespace std;

typedef string ElementType;  // type of item to be stored

class Queue{

    public:
        int size() const; //return the number of elements in the queue
        bool empty() const; //return true if queue is empty, else return false
        void enqueue(ElementType x); //add x to the queue, increasing size()
        void dequeue(); //remove the element most recently added to the queue, decreasing size()
        ElementType front(); //return the element most recently added to the queue 
        Queue();
        ~Queue();


    private:
        class Node{
            public:
                ElementType data;
                Node * next;
        };
        Node * head;
        Node * rear;
        int Size;
};
#endif   

// stack cpp file

#include<iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include "Stack.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

using namespace std;

Stack::Stack(){

    Size = 0;
    head = NULL;
}


Stack::~Stack(){

    cout << "destructor called2" <<endl;
    Node* deleter;
    deleter=head;
    Node* temp;

    while(deleter!=NULL){
        temp=deleter;
        deleter=deleter->next;
        delete temp;
    }
}

bool Stack::empty() const {
    if(Size==0){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

int Stack::size() const {

    return Size;
}

void Stack::push(ItemType x){

    Node *newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = x;

    if(Size == 0){
        head = newNode;
        Size++;
    }
    else{
        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;
        Size++;

    }
}

void Stack::pop(){
    Node *newNode;
    if(Size==1){
        newNode=head;
        head=NULL;
        delete newNode;
    }

    else{
        newNode=head;
        head=head->next;
        delete newNode;

    }
    Size--;
}

ItemType Stack::top(){

    return head->data;
}

// stack .h file

#ifndef STACK
#define STACK
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef int ItemType;  // type of item to be stored

class Stack{

    public:
        Stack();
        ~Stack();
        int size() const; //return the number of elements in the stack
        bool empty() const; //return true if stack is empty, else return false
        void push(ItemType x); //add x to the stack, increasing size()
        void pop(); //remove the element most recently added to the stack, decreasing size()
        ItemType top(); //return the element most recently added to the stack 


    private:
        class Node{
            public:
                ItemType data;
                Node * next;
        };
        Node * head;
        int Size;
};
#endif   

//test .cpp file where operations happen and main is


#include "Stack.h"
#include "Queue.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void operatorAndWriter(Queue& k, Stack &l, ofstream &myfile);
void reader(Queue &loko, Stack &l);

int main(){
    Stack l;
    Queue at;
    reader(at, l);
    return 0;
}

void reader(Queue &loko, Stack &l){

    cout << "Enter the file name : " << endl;
    string filename;
    cin >> filename;
    ifstream meinfile (filename);
    string line;
    string sub;
    ofstream myfile("example.txt");

    while (! meinfile.eof()){

        getline (meinfile, line);
        istringstream iss(line);
        while (iss >> sub){

            loko.enqueue(sub);
        }
        operatorAndWriter(loko, l, myfile);

        meinfile.close();
    }
        myfile.close();

}

void operatorAndWriter(Queue &k, Stack &l, ofstream &myfile){



    if(myfile.is_open()){
            while (k.size()!=0){

                string  op = k.front();
                if (op == "+"){
                    int a = l.top();
                    l.pop();
                    int b = l.top();
                    l.pop();
                    l.push(a+b);
                    myfile << "+ ";
                }
                else if (op == "-"){
                    int a = l.top();
                    l.pop();
                    int b = l.top();
                    l.pop();
                    l.push(b-a);
                    myfile << "- ";
                }
                else if (op == "*"){
                    int a = l.top();
                    l.pop();
                    int b = l.top();
                    l.pop();
                    l.push(a*b);
                    myfile << "* ";
                }
                else if (op == "#"){
                    myfile << "# " ;
                    myfile  << l.top() << endl;
                    l.pop();
                }
                else{
                    int y;
                    y=atoi(op.c_str());
                    l.push(y);
                    myfile <<l.top()<<" ";
                }

                k.dequeue();
            }
    }
}

// here is the input file

23 4 * 19 2 - + #
6 3 -  #
36 #

// here is my example file which i tried create and write operations and their solutions in it. however there is just one solution which belongs to the first sentence of the a.txt file.

23 4 * 19 2 - + # 109
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is *way* too much code. Please read [MCVE]( http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you ask a question, it should be a question and not a tag cloud

Comment: i think a google of infix to postfix should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a lot of code. First some stylistic advice:
Use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.
2. you should check if the File actually exists so you don't corrupt your memory by accident. 
3. Simplify your code, and only post the important part.
4. Include guards should end with `_H`

Now to your problem:
I didn't read all of your code but first of all you can simplify your reading function by writing something like this:

```
ifstream meinfile ("input.txt",ios::in);
while (getline (meinfile,line)){
    // Use line here
}
```

I don't know if this will help, but is a lot of code after all.